# Heroku Redis - What counts as a connection? Why do my connections not drop to zero, after Python Celery completes task?

Tags: django, heroku, redis, celery

I am using the Heroku Redis add-on for my Django application, as the broker for my Python Celery background tasks.

The Celery background task is successfully completed using Heroku Redis as the broker. However within the Heroku Redis add-on dashboard (data.heroku.com/datastores/) it still says there are 8 clients (connections). 1) Why is that, I thought it would be 0 clients (connections) since the celery background task is completed.

2)In the Heroku Redis dashboard the number of clients so far has varied between 13 and 8 clients. Why so many clients? I am only running a single python celery background task at a time, so thought it would always say 1 client.

**Edit:**
I did just add `CELERY_IGNORE_RESULT=True` to my Django settings file based on [Celery with Redis broker in Django: tasks successfully execute, but too many persistent Redis keys and connections remain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54227369/) However the issue of 8+ connections always appearing persists.

Answer (score 0):

See if the numer of connections drop when you run celery `--without-heartbeat`

See [explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20957134/celery-heartbeat-not-working/21038204#21038204)

**Update**:

also try using the [client list](https://redis.io/commands/client-list) command to identify the connection sources. If they are all from celery, then a dipper dig into `celery` is required.